# Is there a way to see the push logs of a public repo in the public github?

Tags: git, github

A public github repo shows the timestamp of the commits.
However, this has nothing to do with the timestamp of pushing the repo into github. The enterprise version of github allows to see the push logs (and so, the timestamps):
https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.20/admin/installation/viewing-push-logs

Is there a way to see the push logs (or at least the timestamps) of a public repo in the public github (instead of in the enterprise version of github)?

Example:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World
$ cd Hello-World

# this shows the commit timestamps, but it does not show when the user pushed these commits into github (it could be a year later):
$ git log
commit 7fd1a60b01f91b314f59955a4e4d4e80d8edf11d (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
Merge: 553c207 7629413
Author: The Octocat <octocat@nowhere.com>
Date:   Tue Mar 6 15:06:50 2012 -0800

    Merge pull request #6 from Spaceghost/patch-1
    
    New line at end of file.

commit 762941318ee16e59dabbacb1b4049eec22f0d303
Author: Johnneylee Jack Rollins <Johnneylee.rollins@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Sep 13 21:42:41 2011 -0700

    New line at end of file. --Signed off by Spaceghost

commit 553c2077f0edc3d5dc5d17262f6aa498e69d6f8e
Author: cameronmcefee <cameron@github.com>
Date:   Wed Jan 26 11:06:08 2011 -0800

    first commit


# this shows the reflog of the locally cloned repo (just a git clone operation):
$ git reflog show master
7fd1a60 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) master@{0}: clone: from https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World



# this shows the reflog at github, but unfortunatelly it returns empty:
$ git reflog show origin/master
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mentioned before the [poor man reflog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28958418/6309) for GitHub, relying on the [GitHub Event API](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/) to list push events.

That would give an idea of when pushes have been made.
I mentioned [those here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18733424/6309), knowing that [public events are delayed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51755288/6309) by a few minutes.