# Restore GitHub commit history while setting new remote origin

Tags: git, github

I had a git repo called `chess_assess`.

- I downgraded my local project's Vue from v3.x to v2.x by creating a new local project called `chess_assess2` and copying almost all content from `chess_assess` into it.
- I then deleted `chess_assess` and renamed `chess_assess2` to `chess_assess`.
- Finally, I reset the remote using

  - `git remote add origin <path_to_chess_assess.git>`
  - `git add . && git commit -m ""`
  - `git push -u origin main`

This produced the error

```
! [rejected]        main -> main (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/hexaquarks/chess_assess.git'
```

So I did:

```
git push -u origin main --force
```

which worked, but now my GitHub repo commits history is completely gone.

Is there a way to reobtain the commit history of my project while simultaneously connecting *this* new project to GitHub?

Comment: Use the reflog to get the hash of the last commit in the deleted branch and recreate a branch on this commit.

Comment: @Philippe `$ git reflog` just shows the last commit I did, that is the commit that overwritten all my previous commits, nothing else. How can I use reflog in the deleted branch when the initial folder `chess_assess` is deleted?

Comment: There is no *easy* way. GitHub have a habit of not actually deleting any commits, though—either for a long time, or perhaps even ever?—so if you contact GitHub support (you may also need to fork over some dollars, I don't know about this part) they may be able to get you your commits back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I use reflog in the deleted branch when the initial folder chess_assess is deleted?

You cannot indeed.

If the remote repository remained the same, check its [own remote reflog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28958418/6309) for GitHub, using the [GitHub Event API](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/) to list push events.
I mentioned [those here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18733424/6309), knowing that [public events are delayed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51755288/6309) by a few minutes.

You might get the last pushed commit, which you can then fetch, bringing with its all its past commits.